# Multiple distinct sessions on a single site

Tags: firefox, testing, google-chrome, session-cookies

Is there a browser or plugin that can handle multiple cookie sessions on a same site?

When developing a website, it's a common pattern to test if it behaves correctly for different users and roles (could be anonymous, admin, moderator, name'em). The more roles your website has , the more testing you will do.

We're getting used to opening 2-3 different browsers to get distinct sessions, but it's getting impractical for complex -and efficient- testing.

Hint: Chrome has an "Incognito Window" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try Firefox with different profiles created for each test user, launching so:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "profileNameForUser1" -no-remote
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Yoono for Firefox this sort of thing.

It's designed to help out with your multiple social network accounts, but it works for any website. It allows for different sessions in different tabs of the **same browser window**.

After installing, you'll likely want to hide the toolbar Yoono adds (left side of the screen -> right click -> close), and then use the 'Yoono profile selector' (just left of the url) to add several profiles, each with the same url of the site you want to use your multiple sessions with.

When you've added your profiles, you can open those profiles (with the 'Yoono profile selector') in different tabs, and enjoy browsing the same web site with different sessions in the same browser window.

Once your tab is in a different session, be careful not to manually put a new address in the address bar, cause that will get you back to the default browser session.

Answer (score 0):

Same for chrome

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/browser_tmp_whatever
```

As many windows as you want

Answer (score 0):

The extension [Multifox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/) accomplishes this.